# MapServer slow rendering on Leaflet viewer

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, wms, mapserver

I am trying to use display shapefile data on top of raster images using Leaflet.
I render the shapefile data using leaflet L.tileLayer.wms function.

The size of shapefile is 300mb. The problem is that the rendering is crazy slow when I use MapServer. It takes almost a minute to render it on raster images.

I did the same thing using GeoServer with Leaflet and it rendered the same shapefile almost instantly.

This is the Leaflet viewer I Used for both MapServer and GeoServer.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet WMS and XYZ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
      var map = L.map("map").setView([30.479506155652967, 71.2240726004029], 5);
      
     //This is the raster images stored locally on my disk.
      var xyz = L.tileLayer(
        "http:/localhost:3000/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        {
          attribution:
            'This renders raster images as basemap which was downloaded from open street map'
        }
      );


      //This is the mapserver link which uses wms to render shapefile
      //Notes: This is using mapserver In case of Geoserver I simply replace it
      // with geoserver link.
      var wms_layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
        "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/msolp/mymap.map",
        {
          layers: "road",
          format: "image/png",
          transparent: true,
          version: "1.1.0",
          attribution: "ROADS"
        }
      );

      var baseLayers = {
        XYZ: xyz
      };

      var overlays = {
        WMS: wms_layer
      };

      var control = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

      xyz.addTo(map);
      wms_layer.addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**As for Mapfile This is is how my mapfile look likes**

```
MAP
  NAME "MyMap"
  STATUS ON
  SIZE 400 300
  EXTENT 60.817362 24.043970 77.126716 37.143147
  UNITS DD
  SHAPEPATH "data"
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END 

  WEB
    IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
    IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    METADATA
      "tile_map_edge_buffer" "10"
      "tile_metatile_level" "0"
      "wms_title" "My Global Map WMS Server"
      "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/msolp/mymap.map" #must change mapfile path
      "wms_srs"             "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:4269"
      "wms_enable_request"  "*"
    END
  END

 
  LAYER
    NAME road
    TYPE LINE
    DATA "gis_osm_roads_free_1.shp"
    STATUS DEFAULT
    CLASS
      STYLE
        COLOR 255 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 255
      END
    END


  
  END



END
```

Comment: Does your shapefile has a spatial index file .qix? If it is missing, create it with shptree and see if it helps. But a minute is so long time that there is probably some other fundamental issue. Is the MapServer layer also slow in QGIS?

Comment: @user30184 its not a minute but solid 30-35 seconds and takes even longer when I zoom in and zoom out since it loads again for every zoom level. I have found tilemode in mapserver which servers only the requested tile of that specific zoom level which might help in increasing the speed significantly but the problem is I cannot get it to work with leaflet. I haven't tried using it with qgis let me check but Geoserver renders the shapefile much faster. Also qix is present

Comment: Update I tried it with qgis it is giving fast enough speed considering how big the size of the file is.

Comment: Do you run MapServer as cgi or fcgi? Time to start cgi may pile up with many small tiled requests.

Comment: @user30184 i use cgi

Comment: Try fcgi so you can make a comparison.

Comment: Try adding `EXTENT 60.817362 24.043970 77.126716 37.143147` to your `LAYER` definition

Comment: @geographika it already is present in the mapfile. Under the map object on 5th line from the top. Update(I added Extent to layer definition too no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try and avoid using tiles when accessing dynamically generated data, and instead request a single WMS image. This will avoid reading from the large file 20-30 times each time you move around the map.

I'm not sure Leaflet supports this without plugins. https://github.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer is one plugin that should support it (see also thread at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6936).

You can test with OpenLayers to see if there is a difference in speed - https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html